# Space of bounded measures metrisable

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, analysis

If $X$ is a compact space and $C(X)$ is separable, then is it true that $C(X)^*$ is metrisable (in terms of weak-*-topology)?

More generally if $A\subseteq C(X)$ is a closed, separable subspace then is it true that $A^*$ is metrisable?

Comment: Only if $C(X)$ (resp. $A$) is finite-dimensional. The weak$^{\ast}$ topology on $Y^{\ast}$ is metrisable if and only if the dimension of $Y$ is $\leqslant \aleph_0$.

Comment: Isn't the separability playing any role here?

Comment: No, that has no influence on the metrisability of the weak$^{\ast}$ topology on $Y^{\ast}$. It has an influence on the metrisability of the closed unit ball (or more generally, bounded subsets) of $Y^{\ast}$ in the weak$^{\ast}$ topology. A bounded subset of $Y^{\ast}$ is metrisable in the weak$^{\ast}$ topology if $Y$ is separable, but not the full space (unless $\dim Y \leqslant \aleph_0$, which for Banach spaces means finite dimension).

Comment: Ok thank you for your answer.